# MySQL: Error 1064 (42000): 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; What am I doing wrong?

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO PAGES pages (subjectId, menuName, position, visible, content)
 (1, 'Our Mission', 1, 1, 'Our mission has been to...');
```

Comment: should be `insert into pages (subjectId, menuName, position, visible, content) values (1, 'Our Mission', 1, 1, 'Our mission has been to...');`

Comment: THANK YOU KIND STRANGER!